# Is this Set of Bessel Functions a Basis for All $C^{1}[0,a]$ Functions?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions, sturm-liouville

Consider the following set of Bessel functions

$$\{J_1(\alpha_ir)\}, \qquad J_0(\alpha_ia)=0 \tag{1}$$

I want to show that this set of functions form a basis for the space of $C^{1}[0,a]$ functions. So I should prove that

> They are linearly independent and that they span the space so they form a basis for that space.

---

**My Work**

My first thought was to find the corresponding Sturm-Liouville problem for this set of functions. However, I failed to find proper boundary conditions. For example, the following Sturm-Liouville system

\begin{align}
\,&\frac{d}{dr}\left[r\frac{dR}{dr}\right]+\left[\lambda r + \frac{1}{r}\right]R=0\\
&R(0)<\infty\\
&R(a)=0
\tag{2}
\end{align}
leads to the following basis
$$\{J_1(\alpha_ir)\}, \qquad J_1(\alpha_ia)=0 \tag{3}$$
for the aforementioned space (note the order of the Bessel functions).

Anyway, I could show that the set of functions mentioned in Eq.$(1)$ are orthogonal and consequently linearly independent by just computing the following integral

$$\int_{0}^{a} r J_1(\alpha r) J_1(\beta r)dr = \frac{a}{\alpha^2-\beta^2}\Big(\beta J_0(\beta a)J_1(\alpha a)- \alpha J_0(\alpha a)J_1(\beta a)\Big)$$

Comment: Completeness in $L_r(0,a)$ is not easy. And your second statement is false: the eigenfunctions $J_1(\alpha_n r)$ are not dense in $C[0,a]$ in the sup norm because all of these functions vanish at $r=0$.

Comment: @TrialAndError: 1.Let me simplify the question. Forget about the completeness and just think about the set being a basis for that space. :) 2.Except at $r=0,a$ the eigen-functions series should converge point wise to continuous functions on $(0,a)$. right?

Comment: Not pointwise to a continuous function because that does not happen for the ordinary Fourier series. More than just continuity is needed. The series will converge in $L^2_r(0,a)$ to the function, and it is probably the case that it will converge in $(0,a)$ in the same way the ordinary Fourier series would. Nothing is easily proved though.

Comment: @TrialAndError: Ah! Sorry! My emphasis on this question was not on the smoothness and so I was careless about it. Consider the space $C^{\infty}[0,a]$. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured out that my first idea will work. The Sturm-Liouville system

\begin{align}
\,&\frac{d}{dr}\left[r\frac{dR}{dr}\right]+\left[\lambda r + \frac{1}{r}\right]R=0\\
&R(0)<\infty\\
&a\frac{dR}{dr}(a)+R(a)=0
\tag{1}
\end{align}

will lead to the eigen-functions

$$\{J_1(\alpha_ir)\}, \qquad J_0(\alpha_ia)=0 \tag{2}$$

I leave the proof as an exercise for the interested reader and just mention a key **Hint** to crack the problem.

$$\frac{dJ_1(\alpha r)}{dr}=\alpha J_0(\alpha r) -\frac{1}{r}J_1(\alpha r) \tag{3}$$

Answer (score 2):

I verified that the Fourier Bessel on $(0,b)$ converges in the same way that the ordinary Fourier series on the same interval does. Titchmarsh was the old master of pointwise convergence proofs for general eigenfunction expansions of second order ODEs. I recommend always starting with his work when looking at the subject of pointwise convergence for generalized Fourier integral and series expansions.

Reference: E. C. Titchmarsh, *Eigenfunction Expansions Associated with Second-Order Differential Equations*, Part I, Second Edition, 1962, Chapter 4, page 84.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the classic and nice reference. :)

Comment: I think that I found it. Take a look at my answer and see if it is OK. :)

Comment: @H.R. : I don't know what you're hinting at.

Comment: With the last identity mentioned there, you can show that the BCs in the mentioned Sturm-Liouville system reduce to $J_0(\alpha a)=0$. Also, $J_1(\alpha r)$ satisfies the ode. So we can use the Sturm-Liouville theorems for convergence and expansions. :)

Comment: @H.R. : For the Bessel equation with parameter $\nu \ge 0$, there are two endpoint functionals at $r=0$ for $0 \le \nu < 1$ (limit-circle case) and there are no endpoint functionals at $r=0$ for $\nu \ge 1$ (limi-point case.) So the problem for $\nu=0$ corresponding to $J_0$ can have a condition at $r=0$ and at $r=1$. The condition at $r=1$ is $\cos\alpha f(1)+\sin\alpha f'(1)=0$. The condition at $r=0$ involves an asymptotic behavior near $0$ with two constants. One case of setting one of the constants to $0$ at $r=0$ corresponds to a requirement of boundedness at $r=0$, which is classical.

Comment: Have I done anything wrong? I don't get your point?

Comment: @H.R. : There is nothing unique in the $J_0$ expansion, which you seemed to point toward. I could not tell. So I wanted to point out there are other expansions on $[0,1]$ involving $J_0$, $K_0$, and you can still have the condition where the combination vanishes at $r=1$. There is a one-parameter family of endpoint conditions for $\nu=0$ at both endpoints of $[0,1]$.

Comment: @H.R. : Also, I don't see how you proving density.

Comment: As far as I know the eigen-functions of a Sturm-Liouville system are unique up to a constant multiplier! right? Also the eigen-function are $J_1$ not $J_0$. My reasoning is simple, since the set of functions introduced is the solution of a Sturm-Liouville system then they form a basis for the aforementioned space. That's all.

Comment: @H.R. For regular Sturm-Liouville problems, with standard endpoint conditions, you get a basis in $L^2_w[a,b]$. Singular endpoints change that because you may not have classical eigenfunctions that are in $L^2$, and the endpoint conditions (if any) are tricky. Your problem is singular, not regular. So theorems about regular problems don't apply. And the uniform completion of eigenfunctions $J_1(\alpha_n r)$ won't include all of $C^{\infty}$ because of the endpoint conditions. Something is not being clearly defined.